# Docker stack - wait for it

Tags: java, docker

I would like to start two services in a stack.

1. Mysql
2. Spring boot app

The main problem is that spring boot starts before database (or starts when connection to database is not allowed). Then in logs I could see: `java.net.UnknownHostException: database`.

We could use startup order:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

So what I do? I copy `wait-for-it.sh` to file with docker-compose, add line
`command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "database:3306", "--", "java -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -jar app.jar"]`

**The result is:**

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid argument syntax: --`

My `entrypoint` in backend `Dockerfile`:

`ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.profiles.active=prod", "-jar","app.jar"]`

**How to make that spring boot app will wait for MySQL database under docker stack?**

Comment: have you tried using "depends_on" in your docker-compose?

Comment: @TomElias of course, but remember

Service could be ready, but does not allow to connect - that's this case

Service of DB is up but spring boot still could not connect

Comment: If you have properly defined the readiness probe, then the DB contaner will be marked as ready only when accepting connections.

Comment: @gusto2 This is my healthcheck     `healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 10
      interval: 60s`

Comment: Now I see the `UnknownHostException`. Assuming using the docker-compose - does it fixes the exception fix itself later when the pods are runniing? (your app should as well survive DB unavailibility) if you have correctly setup the dependency and network, the host should be known. As well you may define an "host alias" in the compose file to be sure the hostname is defined in the network

Comment: Yes, my app will restart a few times and then will work, but I think better will be if just simply wait when database will start

Answer (score 0):

When you run the container, [the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` are combined](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact).  In your example you've set `ENTRYPOINT` to run the Java process, but then override `CMD` in the `docker-compose.yml`: instead of actually running the `wait-for-it.sh` script, it just gets passed as extra parameters to the JVM.

A typical pattern for using both of these together is to have `ENTRYPOINT` be some sort of wrapper that does first-time setup, then takes `CMD` as additional parameters.  For this to work `CMD` needs to be a complete shell command.  Change the Dockerfile to look like:

```sh
COPY wait-for-it.sh entrypoint.sh .
# ENTRYPOINT _must_ be in JSON-array form
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
# CMD may be either string or JSON-array form
# (This is exactly what you originally had as ENTRYPOINT)
CMD ["java", "-Dspring.profiles.active=prod", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

The entrypoint script can be very simple:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# Wait for the database to be up
if [ -n "$MYSQL_HOST" ]; then
    ./wait-for-it.sh "$MYSQL_HOST:3306"
fi
# Run the CMD
exec "$@"
```

The important detail here is that I've configured the database host to be passed as an environment variable.  This requires a shell to run to expand it, which is tricky to do in the JSON-array `ENTRYPOINT` syntax, so I've moved it into a separate script.

Finally, in the `docker-compose.yml`, do not override `command:` (or `entrypoint:`), but do make sure to set the environment variable for the script to be able to find the database.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  database: { ... }
  application:
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: database
    depends_on:
      - database
    # no command: override
```

The wrapper here will run whenever the container starts up, so if you `docker-compose run application bash` to get an interactive shell based on the image, it will still wait for the database to be up.

If you control both the Dockerfile and the `docker-compose.yml`, you shouldn't usually need to override `command:` in the Compose settings.  I find the entrypoint-wrapper pattern useful enough that I generally default to using `CMD` in my Dockerfiles (there is no requirement to have an `ENTRYPOINT`).